# Secure Free Proxy?

Tags: vpn, proxy, privacy

I want a TOR/VPN type application, that I can proxy my connection through for free. Also, I need to be sure that it doesn't save logs of what I browse, and it isn't sniffing my traffic or misusing the information that passes through it (not saving login info etc).

Is it possible to secure my connection over Tor, so that the last relay in my connection can't sniff my traffic? Is there some form of VPN or encryption that I can use, so I can say, log in to securely to my Hotmail or Gmail account without the proxy being able to see my password? 
Or are any of the free proxy sites available on the internet, like nuip.net and hidemyass.com trustable?
There are also some apps like iPad, some of which allow you to create a VPN connection to their server and then browse the net so that your connection is proxied through their server. Are any of them free and trustable?

I basically just want a way to anonymize my surfing for free while being able to trust the service. The service could be ad-supported or volunteer hosted or something...

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to secure my connection over Tor, so that the last relay in my connection can't sniff my traffic? Is there some form of VPN or encryption that I can use, so I can say, log in to securely to my hotmail or gmail account without the proxy being able to see my password?

No. Any kind of proxy, VPN or other anonymizing system ultimately needs to connect using plain text if you are accessing HTTP websites.
However, websites that provide **HTTPS** will provide full encryption from your PC to the webserver, with or without intermediary proxies. Unfortunately, many websites don't offer HTTPS or only do for the Login page, and then force you to access the data via plain-text.

For example, Hotmail provides HTTPS for the login, but **all your email will be transferred in plain-text!**
Gmail on the other hand provides full HTTPS connection throughout your whole connection, so everything will be safe from eavesdrop. Use the URL: https://mail.google.com

As a rule of thumb, don't transfer any kind of sensitive data over a non secure HTTP connection, with or without proxys. If the website doesn't provide a secure connection, don't use it!

PS: when an "Invalid Certificate" warning appears in your browser, don't trust the connection either, as the webserver is not authenticated, so you don't know if you're connecting to the real website or a phising scam site.

Answer (score 0):

[Guardster's free proxy](http://www.guardster.com/?Services-Free_Web_Proxy) service lets you browse the web anonymously. To use, simply put in the URL you wish to browse to in the form at the top of this page and hit "Go." Features

- - Guard your IP address
  - Surf Anonymously
  - Block cookies
  - Stop javascript
  - Block annoying ads
  - Hide images when you want
  - Hide your identity
  - Your Internet privacy is our business!
  - Hide your identity

Answer (score 0):

The software [JonDo](http://anonymous-proxy-servers.net/en/jondo/download) is open source and free of charge. Feel free to edit the code and to link and distribute the program.